# How to calculate minimum optical power required from datasheet of camera sensor?

Tags: power, camera

How can I determine from the datasheet of a camera sensor the minimum optical power required to see a spot on the image?

I have 2 lasers with a diameter of 0.35 mm with respectively a power of 12nW/mm^2 and 900nw/mm^2. I want to know whether the camera is able to detect the lasers.

For my purpose I am not allowed to use any lenses. So the cameras I am looking at, only contains a sensor without a lens.

Kind regards,
Robin

Comment: Can we see the datasheet ?

Comment: I have asked some companies about this and the more advanced they give these values.